# How to make sure, when mod_wsgi is loaded, Apache is running the module

Tags: python, macos, apache, mod-wsgi

On an OS X server, I followed the mod_wsgi installation instructions and when I run `apachectl -M` the output says that mod_wsgi is loaded. On the other hand, when opening the Apache logs after restarting the service, there is no indication that mod_wsgi is loaded. I have tried using mod_wsgi-express and recompiling and reinstalling mod_wsgi, but to no avail. How would I make sure that mod_wsgi is actually being loaded by Apache?

Comment: The mod_wsgi-express stands as a distinct setup to your main Apache, it doesn't come into the picture if you want to install mod_wsgi from source code yourself and manually configure Apache. You will need to indicate what configuration you added into Apache configuration files and show what the actual error is.

Answer (score 0):

Add this section to your Apache config (perhaps in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`) and see if it errors?

```
WSGISocketPrefix /var/run/wsgi

<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName yoursite.com

  WSGIDaemonProcess yoursite-http python-home=/home/vagrant/.virtualenvs/yoursite
  WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/yoursite/yoursite/wsgi.py process-group=yoursite-http application-group=%{GLOBAL}
  <Directory /var/www/html/yoursite/yoursite>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  WSGIProcessGroup yoursite-http
</Virtualhost>
```

Comment: Recommended practice is that when using a daemon process group for a single application you set ``application-group`` to ``%{GLOBAL}`` not some named sub interpreter. That special value ensures the main interpreter context is used, which avoids problems with some third party C extensions which haven't been implemented correctly for sub interpreters.